Cython : How can we properly call add, sub, mul & divide operator?
In .pxd file, I wrote
    _Point operator+(const _Point other) const
    _Point operator -(const _Point other) const
    bool operator==(const _Point other) const

In .pyx file, I wrote
def __eq__(self, Point other):
    cdef _Point* selfptr = self.c_point.get()
    cdef _Point* otherptr = other.c_point.get()
    return selfptr[0] == otherptr[0]

But it comes to operators like __add__ , I cannot do the same thing like ==.
def __add__(self, Point other):
    cdef _Point * selfptr = self.c_point.get()
    cdef _Point * otherptr = other.c_point.get()
    return selfptr[0] + otherptr[0]

Error Message
    × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [27 lines of output]
          
          Error compiling Cython file:
          ------------------------------------------------------------
          ...
                  return not self.__eq__(other)
          
              def __add__(self, Point other):
                  cdef _Point * selfptr = self.c_point.get()
                  cdef _Point * otherptr = other.c_point.get()
                  return selfptr[0] + otherptr[0]
                                    ^
          ------------------------------------------------------------
          
          src/Geometry/Point/Point.pyx:170:26: Cannot convert '_Point' to Python object

How can I fix this? Thank you

The answer you have already is pretty comprehensive and should be enough for you to adapt to your own code. Your code is not complete enough for anyone else to answer more specifically. I don't know what you hope to achieve with this bounty.

+1 what David said. The bounty reason is "Please answer the question based on my code" — but you didn't provide your code! Not even a link to it! So how's anyone supposed to do that?

Since you didn't add a minimal working code, it is hard to provide comlete working code for you. Here are my thoughts: Cython cannot convert _Point C struct directly to a Python object when trying to return the result of selfptr[0] + otherptr[0]. So define a Python wrapper for _Point and then In __add__ function, allocate a new _Point using cdef _Point result, and calculate the result using result.x = selfptr[0] + otherptr[0], then convert result to its Python counterpart by return Point.from_c_point(&result).

the error is simply stating that the returned _Point is not a Python object, you have to wrap it in a python object, one way is to construct another PyPoint and move the return into the contained object.
# distutils: language = c++

cdef extern from *:
    """
    class Value
    {
      public:
      int m_val;
      Value(): m_val(0) {}
      Value(int val): m_val(val) {}
      Value operator+(const Value& other) const { return m_val + other.m_val;} 
    };
    """

    cdef cppclass Value:
        Value(int) noexcept
        Value operator+(Value) const

cdef class PyValue:
    cdef Value* val

    def __cinit__(self, int value):
      self.val = new Value(value)

    def __dealloc__(self):
      del self.val

    def __add__(self, PyValue other):
      ret_val = PyValue(0)
      ret_val.val[0] = self.val[0] + other.val[0]
      return ret_val


For some reason, ret_val.val[0] = self.val[0] + other.val[0] didn't work

@PunreachRany this example that i posted works on the latest cython, so you will have to figure out why your (not shown) class produces that (not shown) error, this example requires the class to be move or copy assignable, otherwise at least you need your class to be move constructible and you instead create a new object on the heap ret_val.val = new Value(....)

@PunreachRany in your example you use .get() so if you are using smart pointers you need to do .get()[0] , because smart pointers don't support indexing.
